# Issues with conflicting declarations and type redeclaration on PIC18F87f22 (C language)

Tags: c, types, declaration

I would first like to apologize for my bad English and also for my ***very*** basic skills with C language. I am really struggling.

I'm currently trying to implement a cascade PID regulation for a DC motor. I'm using a PIC1887f22 for my regulation and am coding with MPLAB X IDE 4.05.

I'm having some issues while trying to build the project, and I need some guidance from you guys.

Here is the prototype/declaration of my PID function in a file called mcc.c

```
int16_t PID_Courant(int16_t erreur_courant, int16_t consigne_courant,int16_t 
integrale_courant, int16_t kp_courant, int16_t ki_courant, int16_t 
kd_courant,int16_t wind_up_flag_courant)
{
    int32_t prop=0;
    int32_t dev=0;
    int16_t Erreur_courant_old=0;
    int32_t integra=0;
    int32_t u=0;
    int16_t a=0;

    Erreur_courant_old = erreur_courant;
    a = get_courant();
    erreur_courant = consigne_courant-a;
    prop = kp_courant * erreur_courant;

    if(!wind_up_flag_courant)
    {
        integrale_courant = integrale_courant + erreur_courant;
    }

    integra = ki_courant * integrale_courant;
    dev = erreur_courant-Erreur_courant_old;
    u = prop + integra + dev;
    u = u/100000000;
    if (abs(u)>TENSION_MAX)
    {
        wind_up_flag_courant=1;
        if(u<0)
        {
            u=-TENSION_MAX;
        }
        else
        {
            u=TENSION_MAX;
        }
    }

    return u;
}
```

The parameters of the function are all declared as global variables in my main.c (before my main function) as follows:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include"mcc_generated_files/epwm1.h"
#include"mcc_generated_files/epwm2.h"
#include"mcc_generated_files/epwm3.h" 
#include"mcc_generated_files/interrupt_manager.h"
#include"mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include"mcc_generated_files/tmr2.h"
#include"mcc_generated_files/pin_manager.h"
#define KE 1
#define KC 1
#define TE_COURANT 0.00001
#define TE_VITESSE 0.0001
#define VITESSE_MAX 60000
#define COURANT_MAX 50000 //mA
#define TENSION_MAX 240000 //mV
int16_t Security_flag=1;
int Stop_flag=1;
int Start_flag=0;
int Wind_up_flag_courant=0;
int Wind_up_flag_vitesse=0;
int Emergency_flag=0;
int Choix_Mode=0;
int16_t MESURE_COURANT=0;
int16_t MESURE_VITESSE=0;
int16_t Consigne_courant =0;
int16_t Consigne_vitesse = 0;
int16_t Kp_courant=0;
int16_t Ki_courant=0;
int16_t Kd_courant=0;
int16_t Kp_vitesse=0;
int16_t Ki_vitesse=0;
int16_t Kd_vitesse=0;
int16_t Erreur_courant=0;
int16_t Erreur_vitesse=0;
int32_t Integrale_courant=0;
int32_t Integrale_vitesse=0;
```

The trick is that inside of the `PID_Courant` function, I modify the variables that are used to call the function, and I'm not really sure if that is ok for my compiler. Anyway, I'm getting these error codes:

> ```
> mcc_generated_files/mcc.c:116: error: (984) type redeclared
> ```

and:

> ```
> mcc_generated_files/mcc.c:116: error: (1098) conflicting declarations for variable "PID_Courant" (mcc_generated_files/mcc.c:115)
> ```

I can't see what conflicts there are here. Is it because I'm trying to put the result of the multiplication of two `int16_t` into another `int16_t`?

I tried switching some of those variables to `int32_t`, but it changed nothing.

Here is the full code of my main.c:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include"mcc_generated_files/epwm1.h"
#include"mcc_generated_files/epwm2.h"
#include"mcc_generated_files/epwm3.h"
#include"mcc_generated_files/interrupt_manager.h"
#include"mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include"mcc_generated_files/tmr2.h"
#include"mcc_generated_files/pin_manager.h"

#define KE 1
#define KC 1
#define TE_COURANT 0.00001
#define TE_VITESSE 0.0001

#define VITESSE_MAX 60000
#define COURANT_MAX 50000 //mA
#define TENSION_MAX 240000 //mV
int16_t Security_flag=1;
int Stop_flag=1;
int Start_flag=0;
int Wind_up_flag_courant=0;
int Wind_up_flag_vitesse=0;
int Emergency_flag=0;
int Choix_Mode=0;
int16_t MESURE_COURANT=0;
int16_t MESURE_VITESSE=0;
int16_t Consigne_courant =0;
int16_t Consigne_vitesse = 0;
int16_t Kp_courant=0;
int16_t Ki_courant=0;
int16_t Kd_courant=0;
int16_t Kp_vitesse=0;
int16_t Ki_vitesse=0;
int16_t Kd_vitesse=0;
int16_t Erreur_courant=0;
int16_t Erreur_vitesse=0;
int32_t Integrale_courant=0;
int32_t Integrale_vitesse=0;

void main(void) 
{
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

    TMR2_StartTimer();

    while(!Start_flag)
    {
       ;
    }
    if(Choix_Mode)
    {
        EPWM2_Initialize();
        EPWM3_Initialize();
    }
    else
    {
        EPWM1_Initialize(); 
    }
    Consigne_courant=PID_Vitesse(Erreur_vitesse,Consigne_vitesse,Kp_vitesse,Ki_vitesse,Kd_vitesse,Wind_up_flag_vitesse);
    while(!Stop_flag)
    {
        int16_t tension=0;
        int i=0;
        do
        {
            tension = PID_Courant(Erreur_courant,Consigne_courant,Integrale_courant,Kp_courant,Ki_courant,Kd_courant,Wind_up_flag_courant);
            Put_Rapport_Cyclique(tension,Choix_Mode);
            i++;
        }while(i<10);
       Consigne_courant = PID_Vitesse(Erreur_vitesse,Consigne_vitesse,Integrale_vitesse,Kp_vitesse,Ki_vitesse,Kd_vitesse,Wind_up_flag_vitesse);
       Security_flag = Update_Security_flag();
    }
    if(Choix_Mode)
    {
         STOP_EPWM2();
         STOP_EPWM3(); 
    }
    else
    {
        STOP_EPWM1();
    }
}
```

And here is my mcc.c:

```
#include "mcc.h"
#define A 399/240000
#define B 199/240000
#define VITESSE_MAX 6000
#define COURANT_MAX 5000 //mA
#define TENSION_MAX 24000 //mV

void SYSTEM_Initialize(void)
{
    INTERRUPT_Initialize();
    PIN_MANAGER_Initialize();
    OSCILLATOR_Initialize();
    //EPWM1_Initialize();
    TMR2_Initialize();
    //EPWM2_Initialize();
    //EPWM3_Initialize();
}

void OSCILLATOR_Initialize(void)
{
    // SCS FOSC; IDLEN disabled; IRCF 16MHz_HF; 
    OSCCON = 0x70;
    // SOSCGO disabled; MFIOSEL disabled; 
    OSCCON2 = 0x00;
    // INTSRC INTRC; PLLEN disabled; TUN 0; 
    OSCTUNE = 0x00;
    // ROSEL System Clock(FOSC); ROON disabled; ROSSLP Disabled in Sleep mode; RODIV Fosc; 
    REFOCON = 0x00;
}
int16_t get_courant()
{
    return 1;      
}
int16_t get_vitesse()
{
  return 1; 
}
int16_t PID_Courant(int16_t erreur_courant, int16_t consigne_courant,int16_t integrale_courant, int16_t kp_courant, int16_t ki_courant, int16_t kd_courant,int16_t wind_up_flag_courant)
{
    int32_t prop=0;
    int32_t dev=0;
    int16_t Erreur_courant_old=0;
    int32_t integra=0;
    int32_t u=0;
    int16_t a=0;

    Erreur_courant_old = erreur_courant;
    a = get_courant();
    erreur_courant = consigne_courant-a;
    prop = kp_courant * erreur_courant;

    if(!wind_up_flag_courant)
    {
        integrale_courant = integrale_courant + erreur_courant;
    }

    integra = ki_courant * integrale_courant;
    dev = erreur_courant-Erreur_courant_old;
    u = prop + integra + dev;
    u = u/100000000;
    if (abs(u)>TENSION_MAX)
    {
        wind_up_flag_courant=1;
        if(u<0)
        {
            u=-TENSION_MAX;
        }
        else
        {
            u=TENSION_MAX;
        }
    }

    return u;
}

int16_t PID_Vitesse(int16_t erreur_vitesse, int16_t consigne_vitesse,int16_t integrale_vitesse ,int16_t Kk_vitesse, int16_t ki_vitesse, int16_t kd_vitesse, int wind_up_flag_vitesse)
{
    int16_t prop=0;
    int16_t dev=0;
    int32_t integra=0;
    int32_t u=0;
    int16_t a=0;
    int16_t Erreur_vitesse_old=0;

    Erreur_vitesse_old = Erreur_vitesse;
    a = get_vitesse();
    Erreur_vitesse = Consigne_vitesse-a;
    prop = Kp_vitesse * Erreur_vitesse;

    if(!Wind_up_flag_vitesse)
    {
        Integrale_vitesse = Integrale_vitesse + Erreur_vitesse;
    }

    integra = Ki_vitesse*Integrale_vitesse;
    dev = Erreur_vitesse-Erreur_vitesse_old;
    u = prop + integra + dev;
    u = u / (1000000);
    if (u>abs(COURANT_MAX))
    {
        Wind_up_flag_vitesse=1;
        if(u<0)
        {
            u=-COURANT_MAX;
        }
        else
        {
            u=COURANT_MAX;
        }
    }

    return u;
}

void Put_Rapport_Cyclique(int16_t u, int choix_mode)
{
    if(choix_mode=1)
    {
        if (u<=0)
        {
            bit_set(CCP1CON,1);
        }
        else
        {
            bit_clr(CCP1CON,1);
        }
        u=A*u;
        EPWM1_LoadDutyValue(u);
    }
    else
    {
        u=199+u*B;
    }
    EPWM2_LoadDutyValue(u);
    EPWM3_LoadDutyValue(u);
}

int Update_Security_flag(void)
{
    int a=0;
    int b=0;

    a=get_courant();
    b=get_vitesse();
    if (abs(a)> COURANT_MAX || abs(b)> VITESSE_MAX)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void STOP_EPWM1(void)
{
    bits_off(CCP1CON,0b00001111);
}
//EPWM1_LoadDutyValue(0);
void STOP_EPWM2(void)
{
    //EPWM2_LoadDutyValue(0);
    bits_off(CCP2CON,0b00001111);
}
void STOP_EPWM3(void)
{
    //EPWM3_LoadDutyValue(0);
    bits_off(CCP3CON, 0b00001111);
}
```

and the mcc.h :

```
#define MCC_H
#include <xc.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include "pin_manager.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "interrupt_manager.h"
#include "epwm1.h"
#include "epwm2.h"
#include "tmr2.h"
#include "epwm3.h"
#define unsigned char  RAPPORT_CYCLIQUE 0
#define bit_set(var,bitno) ((var) |= 1 << (bitno))
#define bit_clr(var,bitno) ((var) &= ~(1 << (bitno)))
#define bits_on(var,mask) var |= mask
#define bits_off(var,mask) var &= ~0 ^ mask
#define _XTAL_FREQ  16000000

/*
 * Initializes the device to the default states configured in the MCC GUI
 */
void SYSTEM_Initialize(void);

/*
 * Initializes the oscillator to the default states configured in the MCC GUI
 */
void OSCILLATOR_Initialize(void);
void STOP_EPWM1(void);
void STOP_EPWM2(void);
void STOP_EPWM3(void);
int16_tget_courant(void);
int16_tget_vitesse(void);
int16_t PID_Courant(int16_t erreur_courant, int16_t consigne_courant, int16_t kp_courant, int16_t ki_courant, int16_t kd_courant,int wind_up_flag_courant);
int16_t PID_Vitesse(int16_t erreur_vitesse, int16_t consigne_vitesse, int16_t kp_vitesse, int16_t ki_vitesse, int16_t kd_vitesse,int wind_up_flag_vitesse);
int16_t Put_Rapport_cyclique(int16_t u, int choix_mode);
int Update_Security_flag(void);
```

Can anyone see a problem here?
What do you think cause these errors ?
Thank you very much for even reading this!!

Comment: Since the error message gives you the line number for the error, you should be able to find where it is, and post a more concise piece of code containing the error.

Comment: Thank you, i do know the problem lies in my PID_Courant(...) function, but i can't see what is wrong with it.

Comment: `PID_Courant` seems to have 5 arguments in one place, and 6 and 7 in other places.

Comment: What Jǝssǝ meant was that you should make the code exhibiting the problem as small as possible, removing all irrelevant parts. It makes it much easier to find the error, and to make others interested in finding the error for you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get a chance to read through your code yesterday (you posted quite a lot of it) but I think I have found your error. In your mcc.h you have declared `PID_courant` as

```
int16_t PID_Courant(int16_t erreur_courant, int16_t consigne_courant, int16_t kp_courant, int16_t ki_courant, int16_t kd_courant,int wind_up_flag_courant);
```

However, in your mcc.c you declare and define it as

```
int16_t PID_Courant(int16_t erreur_courant, int16_t consigne_courant,int16_t integrale_courant, int16_t kp_courant, int16_t ki_courant, int16_t kd_courant,int16_t wind_up_flag_courant)
```

If you compare the two, you will find that the first one (in mcc.h) is missing the third argument, `int16_t integrale_courant`. You also declare the last argument as `int wind_up_flag_courant` it mcc.h but as `int16_t wind_up_flag_courant` in mcc.c.

Essentially, your code tries to change `PID_courant` from how it is declared in mcc.h; i.e. trying to redefine it. This is what throws your error.

Comment: ty very much, i found out a few days ago !

Comment: Great! To mark your question as solved you can mark the answer as correct by clicking the check mark underneath the voting buttons (this will also give you two reputation points)